# Дублирование записей Entity Framework 6 (generic update)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

День добрый.

Сделал аналогично примеру [Many to many Generic update method EF 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830764/many-to-many-generic-update-method-with-entity-framework-6.)

Но в моем случае значения из свойства-коллекции заново создаются в "БД".

```
public void Update(T updateItem)
{
    using (var databaseContext = new TelesystemContext())
    {

        T foundDal = databaseContext.Set<T>().Find(updateItem.Id);
        var entry = databaseContext.Entry(foundDal);
        entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(updateItem);

        var collection = entry.Collection("Permissions");
        collection.Load();
        collection.CurrentValue = typeof(T).GetProperty("Permissions").GetValue(updateItem);


        databaseContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Т.е. `Permissions` каждый раз при сохранении объекта `updateItem` создаются заново, а должны были просто добавиться в таблицу - связку "многие-ко-многим".

Comment: То что используется строковый литерал "Permissions" это только для теста. В общем случае, естественно будет заменено на параметр.

Comment: У вас как-то слишком сложно написано. Достаточно было `databaseContext.Entry(updateItem).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: Это generic реализация. Но все равно элементы коллекции **Permissions** создаются в БД снова. Т.е. имееют состояние **Added**

Comment: Александр, какая разница что там за реализация? Приведенный вам код делает то же самое что и ваш. А ответ я вам написал ниже.

Comment: Ссори, почему то вначале я видел только комментарий.

Comment: Неудивительно - я же его первым написал, а потом начал над ответом думать :)

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в том, что добавленные вами сущности `Permissions` не относятся к контексту - и в итоге оказываются в него добавлены. Вам надо явно пройтись по этим разрешениям - и указать что они находятся в статусе Unchanged:

```
foreach (var p in updateItem.Permissions)
    databaseContext.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

PS поскольку свойство Permissions недоступно напрямую - вам придется придумать как получить к нему доступ. Я намеренно не писал кода для получения этого свойства - потому что он не имеет отношения к задаче.

Comment: Присвоить `EntityState.Unchanged` тоже не правильно. А если они действительно добавились. Как правильно сделать обобщенное решение с отсоединенными сущностями?

Comment: @Александр а это уже вы должны придумать как отслеживать. В общем случае задача решения не имеет.